# parsing dynamic website but can't find request

Tags: json, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this website:

https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/#

and get trademark data based on certain search conditions (for example, getting trademarks which contain certain "love the"). It is a dynamic website so the url doesn't change when I search. I am trying to follow the steps in this stack overflow answer:

[Crawling data but the url doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50988884/crawling-data-but-the-url-doesnt-change)

The answer mentions that after clicking on search button, the network tab on dev tools in browser will show an XRH request and then I can do further JSON parsing on it. I can't find the request for this website (it shows about 20 different requests in network tab though, none seem to change with my query). How do I go about parsing this? Also, could you share what to do after finding the correct request?

Thanks a ton

Comment: I solved the same question before. --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/66697604/7658985

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hard Scraping API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697604/hard-scraping-api)

Comment: hi thanks, i am still very new to parsing dynamic websites. so i have no clue about what to do next with finding qe and qk values so could you please share full code